# How to disable source code publishing in ASP.NET 5 apps?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, publishing, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core

Here is how the deployed content looks like after publishing (on Azure Website):

```
/approot/packages              - NuGet packages
/approot/src                   - all the source files from the solution
/approot/global.json           - a list of global NuGet packages
/wwwroot/bin/AspNet.Loader.dll - the only .dll file in wwwroot folder
/wwwroot/css                   - front-end code
/wwwroot/lib                   - front-end code
/wwwroot/web.config            - auto-generated
```

[web.config](https://gist.github.com/koistya/27e25b0ed647424f2913) generated during publishing

I'm wondering, how to make it deploy only the compiled output and not the source files?

Comment: Can you add more details on how you published your site? Did you use Visual Studio to publish it, Github, WebDeploy, FTP, etc?

Answer (score 9):

- If you are publishing through VS 2015, then make the following selection to not deploy the source files:
  [image]
- If you are not using VS, then you can use `kpm pack` command to achieve this. For example, following is the command that VS uses to create the package to deploy (You can enable `Detailed` logging in Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run, to see this)

  `"C:\Users\kiranchalla\.kre\packages\kre-clr-x86.1.0.0-beta2-10690\bin\kpm.cmd" pack --runtime KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2-10690 --out "C:\Users\kiranchalla\AppData\Local\Temp\AspNetPublish\WebApplication5-91" --wwwroot-out wwwroot --no-source --configuration Release --quiet`

Some info:
The effect of the above is that now your application is pre-compiled and you should see a package under the packages folder and the `kre-app-base` flag in web.config points to this package. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta1" />
    <add key="kre-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta2-10690" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="CLR" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\packages\WebApplication5\1.0.0\root" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```